# Java 10x10 array with nested loop

Tags: java, arraylist, nested, nested-loops

I have an 10x10 array and I am trying to fill it with nested loop

```
int A[][] = new int [10][10];
```

So far I have created this -

```
C = 1;
        for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
            for (j=9-i; j>=7-i; j--) 
                 if (j>=0) {
                    A[i][j] = C; C=C+1;
                }
```

And here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOJRv.png) so far.

But I am trying to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwOfx.png) with two for loops and cannot manage it.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you also show how you arrive at your result?

Comment: I mean how you print out your result. When I run your algorithm, my result looks different (x and y axis are swapped)

Comment: Do not include any image that can be put in as text. Please put as much effort into your question as you expect the volunteers here to put in to answer you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

- iterate rows as usual from 0 to 10, set column index to 9 and decrease it
- in the inner loop, set the range from `i` to the `Math.max(i - beltWidth + 1, 0)` inclusive (`beltWidth` is the maximal count of non-zero values in a column, in this case it's 3).

```java
final int size = 10;
final int beltWidth = 3;
int A[][] = new int [size][size];

int c = 1;
for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size; i++, j--) {
    for (int k = i; k >= Math.max(i - beltWidth + 1, 0); k--) {
        A[k][j] = c++;
    }
}

for (int[] r : A) {
    for (int x : r) {
        System.out.printf("%2d  ", x);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   3   1  
 0   0   0   0   0   0   9   5   2   0  
 0   0   0   0   0  12   8   4   0   0  
 0   0   0   0  15  11   7   0   0   0  
 0   0   0  18  14  10   0   0   0   0  
 0   0  21  17  13   0   0   0   0   0  
 0  24  20  16   0   0   0   0   0   0  
27  23  19   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
26  22   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
25   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version. I borrowed the nice printf formatting from Alex's answer :)
I just wanted to mention 2 things:

1. I think it's a bit easier to read if i and j are called y and x
2. I seem to remember that if you need performance, you need to traverse the array along the x axis, as that is how CPU cache is fetched (at least in theory). That would make the algorithm a bit more complicated, but I guess in this case we are not really concerned with performance so having y in the inner loop is fine :)

```
        int dimension = 10;
        int[][] result = new int[dimension][dimension];

        int C = 27;
        int yOffset = 9;
        for (int x = 0; x < dimension; x++) {
            for (int y = Math.min(2, yOffset); y >= 0 && yOffset - y >= 0; y--) {
                result[yOffset - y][x] = C--;
            }
            yOffset--;
        }

        for (int[] y : result) {
            for (int x : y) {
                System.out.printf("%2d  ", x);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Output

```
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   3   1  
 0   0   0   0   0   0   9   5   2   0  
 0   0   0   0   0  12   8   4   0   0  
 0   0   0   0  15  11   7   0   0   0  
 0   0   0  18  14  10   0   0   0   0  
 0   0  21  17  13   0   0   0   0   0  
 0  24  20  16   0   0   0   0   0   0  
27  23  19   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
26  22   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
25   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```